# How to replace the video track of a part of a video file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, media, mp4

I have an mp4 file like this(same format but longer):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'N1.2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-10-31T13:44:21.000000Z
  Duration: 00:28:54.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10295 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 9972 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-31T13:44:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-31T13:44:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

I also have another video file that is 3 minutes long. and has no audio. What is the fastest way to encode the other video in a way that it is encoded like my main video and then replace the last three minutes of the video track of my original video with this?

In other words.
I have video A that is 1 hour long. With the encoding shown above.

I have video B that is 3 minutes long with no audio. with a random encoding.

I want to have video C with the same encoding and same audio as A. But it's video track would be the first 57 minutes of A + B(which is 3 minutes).

I want to do this as fast as possible so I would like to not re encode A.

I know how to concatenate two videos, I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy res.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make end video using parameters of main video:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i videob.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=sample_rate=48000:channel_layout=stereo -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,format=yuv420p,fps=50[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -video_track_timescale 50000 -shortest videob2.mp4
   ```
2. Get duration of main video:

   ```
   ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 main.mp4
   ```
3. Make `files.txt` which is needed for concat demuxer:

   ```
   file 'main.mp4'
   outpoint 3420
   file 'videob2.mp4'
   ```

   - In this example `outpoint` is main video duration minus end video duration.
4. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -i main.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest output.mp4
   ```

Comment: This is almost good but two questions, how can I specify outpoint automatically equal to the `duration of first video - duration of second video` e.g. 3600s-30s but actually the second video is always 30 seconds but the size of the first video differs(I have so many different ones.) and also the sound is not copied from first video in your method. I need the sound of the first video to be allover the output and only the video of the last 30 seconds should be overridden by the second video not the audio.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay See updated answer. There is no way to specify outpoint automatically equal to the duration of first video - duration of second video, but it can be easily done using your preferred shell / scripting / code language.